# Mock the date for Date.parse

Tags: ruby, date

I am doing some tests on date parsing. I was able to mock the date by doing as below:

```
my_str_date = '08022014at0600 +00:00'
my_new_date = DateTime.strptime(my_str_date, "%d%m%Yat%H%M %z").to_time
Time.stub(:now).and_return(my_new_date)
```

This is good enough most of the time, but when I want to get a date based on the day of the week, I do `Date.parse('wednesday')` for example, and unfortunately, it takes the current date.

I don't know how to find a global solution to simulate a specific date in the year that would work for `Time.now` and `Date.parse`. Any idea?

I though about [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) library, but it does not seem to handle my case.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to specify a certain day just by giving the day of the week? That is impossible; there is not enough information. And it is not clear what kind of strings you intend to pass. Are they always English? Are they always downcased?

Comment: Actually, I have an action which parse a string. One of my case is to get the `Date` of the week, just by giving the full weekday name. The weekday is for sure valid, and I would like to have different tests, which have different "current day", if it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to do a clear integration test on a feature that parse a `String` because `Date.parse` does not use `Time.now` as reference for the current time. So I decided to use `Chronic.parse` from `chronic` gem and not `Date.parse` anymore.

The mock on `Time.now` is now use when I call `Chronic.parse('wednesday')`, and it helps me to check my feature is working properly based on a specific Time.now

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'time'

def get_weekday_date(name, ref = Date.today)
  day = {"sun"=>0, "mon"=>1, "tue"=>2, "wed"=>3, "thu"=>4, "fri"=>5, "sat"=>6}[name[0, 3].downcase]
  ref - ref.wday + day
end

date = get_weekday_date('wed', Date.parse("2010-10-10"))
puts date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %A')  ## 2010-10-13 Wednesday
```

Comment: I am sorry, I think I was not very clear regarding your answer : the target is to write a test, based on the fact that the current day is the 8th of Feb, when I do `Date.parse('wednesday')`, it should return the 12th of Feb, whenever I do the test.

Comment: Oh yes I now follow. I think I can't give the solution you want sorry.